# Call to getText() not compiling in Android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically what I'm trying is getting data from my server and put it to my textview to further upload this data to my firebase realtime database.

My code which posts data to firebase:

```
private void addArtist() {
//getting the values to save
String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();
String email = editTextName1.getText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail()).toString().trim();
```

Error:

[image: problem]

using setText() is it possible ?

Comment: What is `uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail()`?

Comment: My data from server @forpas

Comment: What do you want to do with it? Set it as text to a view? And which view?

Comment: Just want a solution for error depicted in the image above.

Comment: Hi, I don't think you are meant to put anything in the brackets of getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that you're calling the `getText()` method which his only purpose is to get the text inside the view, **not to set it**

To set the text into your `EditText` is enough to go like this:

```
editTextName1.setText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

Although this works, if you want that data to not be modified just use a plain `TextView` and set text there like this:

```
yourTextView.setText(someOfYourVariables.toString());
```

Answer (score 2):

Try it :

```
String email = editTextName1.getText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail().toString());
```

Comment: Same problem still.

Answer (score 0):

The method `getText()` takes no arguments.
So you can't do:

```
editTextName1.getText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail()).toString().trim();
```

Do you want to use `setText()` like this?

```
editTextName1.setText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail().toString().trim());
```

Comment: yes i want to use setText like that but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String email = editTextName1.getText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail()).toString().trim();
```

to

```
   String email = uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail().toString().trim();
editTextName1.setText(email);
```

There is also an error with your Brackets (). You are closing

String email = editTextName1.getText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).**getPlayerEmail())**.toString().trim();

after getPlayerEmail() instead of after the entire statement

String email = editTextName1.getText(uniquePlayerWithImage.getPlayerDetails().get(0).getPlayerEmail().toString().**trim());**